# In Javascript what is the meaning of Object[key] ??=0

Tags: javascript, syntax

I was looking up the reduce method in MDN web docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and came across this syntax but I can't seem to find any reference elsewhere as to what Object[key] ??=0 would mean:

allNames[name] ??= 0;

Here is the snippet from the docs page...

**Counting instances of values in an object**

```
const names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Tiff', 'Bruce', 'Alice'];

const countedNames = names.reduce((allNames, name) => {
  allNames[name] ??= 0;
  allNames[name]++;
  // Remember to return the object, or the next iteration
  // will receive undefined
  return allNames;
}, {});
// countedNames is:
// { 'Alice': 2, 'Bob': 1, 'Tiff': 1, 'Bruce': 1 }
```

Comment: The general rules is that `x <operator>= y` is equivalent to `x = x <operator> y`. So `x ??= y` is short for `x = x ?? y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The logical nullish assignment (x ??= y) operator only assigns if x is nullish (null or undefined).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

In this case `Object[key] ??=0` if Object[key] is null or undefined, it will assign the value 0 to it